# What are the Node Providers for Avalanche Network

Tags: blockchain, nodes, web3-providers

Is there any node providers for Avalanche network so that I can get realtime data from blockchain? I have tried Moralis and Graph, but they have 5-10 seconds lagging behind the blockchain. So I need my own node that i can rent to achieve my goal.

Answer (score 4):

I recommend [Chainstack](https://chainstack.com/). Easy to set up, fast nodes and great support!

1. [Create an account on Chainstack](https://docs.chainstack.com/quickstart/create-an-account)
2. [How to deploy a node on Chainstack](https://docs.chainstack.com/quickstart/deploy-a-network-or-a-node)

They also have a page in the docs with a lot of [JSON-RPC API call examples](https://docs.chainstack.com/api/node-api-reference), and the code actually works!

Answer (score 0):

[Quicknode](https://www.quicknode.com/) is a solid option that you should check out